# Save the Local Area Connection name to a variable

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I'm making a batch script to configure the Ethernet NIC's on multiple Windows 10 tablets, but I have 1 issue. Many of the tablets have different Ethernet names e.g. `Ethernet`, `Ethernet 8`, `Ethernet 11`, and so on.

What command can I run that will find the current ethernet adapter name and store it into a variable?

All of these tablets will have a WiFi adapter attached, so it will always find that one. I need some command that will find the ethernet name. I've seen I can use something called `WMIC`, can that be used on Windows 10? What will be the best course of action?

```
for /F "skip=3 tokens=3*" %G in ('netsh interface show interface') do echo %%H
```

I have this, but I dont know how it will work when finding multiple connections. I have not tested this yet on these tablets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have specifically mentioned [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic), I thought I'd provide an example [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which uses it to retrieve the name of the network connection as it appears in the Network Connections Control Panel.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Eth="&For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%A In ('WMIC NIC Where^
 "AdapterTypeID='0' And NetEnabled='TRUE' And PhysicalAdapter='TRUE'"^
 Get NetConnectionID /Value 2^>Nul')Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%C In ("%%B"
)Do Set "Eth=%%C"
If Not Defined Eth Exit /B
Echo %Eth%&Pause
```

This filters Ethernet 802.3 adapter types as required. The last line was included just to show you the saved variable, you would obviously replace that with your own code, as necessary. I have additionally filtered to specify enabled physical adapters, you may choose not to include those, or may prefer to additionally or instead opt for those with a `NetConnectionStatus` of `2`. There should be sufficient information provided here for you to make such additions or modifications if you so wish.

Comment: thank you that helps a lot. I was worried my question wouldn't make much sense. I have 1 more question that I can't seem to find the answer too. what does the ^ mean/do? I'm seeing it often in WMIC usage and netsh usage all when using the FOR loops...

Comment: It's being used as an escape character, @br34k. In this case I have used it to escape line returns, _(to keep the line length manageable)_, and to escape the redirection character. They have nothing to do with `WMIC` they're `cmd.exe` specific.

Comment: thank you again, you've been a major help. I can use this info to check more into it's usage now. much is appreciated!